# Confusions with Fubini’s Theorem

Tags: integration, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems, product-measure

**Fubini's Theorem**: *Let $\mu,\nu$ be two $\sigma$-finite measures and $f$ be a measurable function.
If $f \ge 0$ or $f \in L^1(\mu\times \nu)$, then
$$ \int f ~d \mu \times \nu = \iint f ~d\mu ~d\nu = \iint f ~d\nu ~d\mu.$$*

---

When $f^+ \in L^1(\mu\times \nu)$, but $f$ may be not integrable: using Fubini's Theorem for $f^+,f^-$, we have that
$$ \int f^+ ~d \mu \times \nu = \iint f^+ ~d\mu ~d\nu = \iint f^+ ~d\nu ~d\mu,$$
$$ \int f^- ~d \mu \times \nu = \iint f^- ~d\mu ~d\nu = \iint f^- ~d\nu ~d\mu.$$
Note that $\int f^+~ d\mu$ is finite $\nu$-a.e. Thus we obtain that
\begin{align*}
  \int f ~d \mu \times \nu & = \int f^+ ~d \mu \times \nu - \int f^- ~d \mu \times \nu \\
  & = \iint f^+ ~d\mu ~d\nu - \iint f^- ~d\mu ~d\nu \\
  & = \int \left(\int f^+ ~d\mu - \int f^- ~d\mu \right)~d\nu \\
  & = \iint f ~d\mu ~d\nu.
\end{align*}
Therefore, the equality in Fubini's Theorem is valid for $f$, where we only have that $f^+ \in L^1(\mu\times \nu)$.

---

**Is there any wrong steps? I'm not sure whether it is true.**

Comment: I think this argument is valid.

Comment: @Ramiro We just need that one of two integrals is finite. Then we can define the integral of $f$ by the equality. We allow the integral to be infinite.

Comment: Yes, It is true. Adding to the theorem  the condition that  $f^+$ or $f^-$ is integrable, your argument is correct.